# R mutate() and case_when() does not add values to the new field

Tags: r

I created a new field where I intend to populate some data(continents) from some vectors, based on data of an existing column(country). There are several datasets involved in the analysis and the code worked perfectly on only the last table, but the other tables which are as much of importance failed to fill in continents to the required column.

```
meats_long <- meats_long %>%
  add_column(Territory = NA)

Africa <- c("Cote d'Ivoire", "Madagascar", "South Africa", "Ghana", "Morocco", "Ethiopia", "Kenya","Egypt")
NorthAmerica <- c("Mexico","Panama","Jamaica", "Dominican Republic","Nicaragua","Honduras","Costa Rica","Guatemala","Canada","El Salvador")
Europe <- c("Iceland","Belgium-Luxembourg","Ukraine","Latvia","Sweden","Greece","Portugal","Russia","Poland","Denmark","Norway","Switzerland","Austria","Germany","Netherlands","Spain","France","Italy","Ireland","United Kingdom")
Asia <- c("Taiwan","Turkey", "Pakistan","Japan","China","Vietnam", "Hong Kong","Thailand","India","Indonesia","Philippines","Korea, South","Malaysia","Israel","Sri Lanka","Pakistan")
Oceania <- c("Australia","Other Pacific Islands, NEC")
SouthAmerica <- c("Uruguay","Bolivia","Colombia","Argentina","Ecuador","Peru","New Zealand", "Brazil","Chile")
Others <- c("Rest of world")

meats_long <- meats_long %>%
  mutate(Territory = case_when(Source %in% Africa ~ "Africa",
                               Source %in% NorthAmerica ~ "North America",
                               Source %in% Europe ~ "Europe",
                               Source %in% Asia ~ "Asia",
                               Source %in% Oceania ~ "Oceania",
                               Source %in% SouthAmerica ~ "South America",
                               Source %in% Others ~ "Rest of world"))
```

[image: Attached is a screenshot of the generated table where the territory field remain NA]

Comment: Are those fixed matches?.  Your column 'Source' shows uppercase characters.  It won't match if there is any difference in case i.e. you may convert to upper case for the vectors and match `Source %in% toupper(Africa) ~ "Africa",..`

Comment: @akrun , thanks very much once again for coming to my aid. The toupper() function worked and the field is populated now.